# Maximum number of Upvotes in a day in Stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, support

I know that it is **40 Upvotes per day** but i **have got 42** today,

[image]

How is this possible?? Why does this happened. Please explain.

Comment: I seem to recall this can happen when posts are deleted. But i'm not certain

Comment: if the post are deleted then doesn't the votes also be removed??

Comment: No. Votes are not removed with post. Otherwise I will delete my heavily downvoted post then undelete it. And [too many duplicates](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=more+than+40+votes).

Comment: if so the deleted post upvotes wont be considered for days maxiumum number of upvotes??

Comment: @hims056 thanks for the link mate :)